# Created popup in js but won't open after closing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I manage to bring the popup, and add a close button, but when it's close, the first function won't trigger the popup again! No idea what I'm doing wrong! The popup was fully working without the close button, but I wanted to add it for UX, to make clear that you can actually show or hide the popup anytime. Here's what I've tried:

```html
<style>
/* Popup container - can be anything you want */
.popup {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

/* The actual popup */
.popup .popuptext {
  visibility: hidden;
/*   background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95); */
  background-color: white;
  color: #3e3e3f;
  padding: 8px 10px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 10%;
  left: 30%;
  margin-left: -80px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 6px 8px -2px rgba(221,221,221,.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 6px 8px -2px rgba(221,221,221,.5);
   box-shadow: 0px 6px 8px -2px rgba(221,221,221,.5);
   
}
  @media screen and (max-width: 767px){
  .popup .popuptext {
    left: 35%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.96);

  }
  }
  
.popuptext {margin: 15px;}

/* Popup arrow */
.popup .popuptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-color: white;

}

/* Toggle this class - hide and show the popup */
.popup .show {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
  animation: fadeIn 1s;
}

/* Add animation (fade in the popup) */
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  from {opacity: 0;} 
  to {opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {opacity: 0;}
  to {opacity:1 ;}
 
}
.lista-popup { 
  width: 550px;
  margin: 10px;
  left: -5px;
  
   }
.lista-info-plants {
  width: 550px;


}
  
@media screen and (max-width:767px){
.lista-info-plants{
  width: 340px;
  margin: 10px;
}
}
  
@media screen and (max-width:767px){
.lista-popup{
  width: 340px;    
  margin: 10px;
}
}

.cerrar-popup{
  visibility: hidden;
  background-color: #ff6b6b;
  color: white;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  font-weight: 700;
  border-radius: 1000px;
  border: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  z-index: 1500;
}
.boton-para-cerrar  {
  padding-left: 90%;
  top: 100px;
}

</style>
<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()"><h2><strong>¿Cómo funciona?</strong></h2>
<div class="popuptext" id="myPopup">
<div class="lista-popup">

  <div class="boton-para-cerrar"><button class="cerrar-popup" onclick="myFunction2()" id="btn-cerrar"> X </button></div>
  <h3>Te explicamos como funciona :)</h3> 
  <ol>
    <li class="lista-info-plants">Selecciona la plantita que quieres, tenemos 3 opciones.</li><br>
    <li class="lista-info-plants">Para enviar las plantitas, utilizamos envío del día siguiente para que tu plantita no sufra.</li><br> 
    <li class="lista-info-plants">El envío del día siguiente cuenta a partir de que la maceta sale de nuestras instalaciones. En realidad necesitamos unos días para sembrar la pantita y empacarla bien.</li><br>
    <li class="lista-info-plants">Por el momento solo enviamos cactus y suculentas, pues son los que mejor aguantan los traslados.</li><br>
    <li class="lista-info-plants">Por último, te recordamos que tener una plantita es como una mascota, hay que cuidar de ella y darle lo que necesita para sobrevivir :) </li><br>
  </ol>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
// When the user clicks on div, open the popup
function myFunction() {
  var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
  popup.classList.toggle("show");
  var btncerrar = document.getElementById("btn-cerrar");
  btncerrar.classList.toggle("show");

}
  function myFunction2() {
  var cerrar = document.getElementById("myPopup");
  cerrar.classList.toggle("hide");
  // var btncerrar2 = document.getElementById("btn-cerrar");
  // btncerrar2.classList.toggle("hide");
}
</script>
```

Comment: Just try to add and remove one class. For example, just add the class show to show the popup and remove it when the user clicks the close button.

Comment: You would need to put all your code (html/css/js/ in the *same* code snippet so that it can run, otherwise i.e. clicking on the button triggers myFunction() which is not defined in that snippet. Can you consider reorganizing your code under one (1) snippet please? Thank you

Comment: @LaurentC sure. I do have it in one snippet, just separated for the post thinking it would be easier to read. I guess it wasn't lol. I just edited the post to show one snippet of code.

Comment: Thank you, I just added a quick fix for your code in the answer box. Thank you. And let me know if that is what you wanted. Tambien hablo espanol :)

Comment: @LaurentC it is very weird because it does work here but not on my full site. Maybe it is a class issue? No estoy seguro!!

Comment: ¿Podría ver su versión live?

Comment: @LaurentC Claro, es un preview, los puedes ver aquí: https://zkuzrjax2mmihlq6-7442563129.shopifypreview.com/collections/macetas/products/copy-of-porta-macetas-de-aluminio-edicion-oro-especial

Después de cerrar el popup, ya no vuelve a abrir

Comment: OK let me check that.

Comment: @Joe_fefs it never shows up because the hide class is still there (think about it, if the default is hide, why would you need the hide class??? it does not make sense, just remove the show class and your pop will display again)

Comment: OK I found a solution, give me 2 minutes to double check and I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed with OP, I am providing a simplified solution and since they already have jQuery loaded on their website page, we can use it without adding any weight. I also simplified the CSS.

```js
function myFunction() {
  $("#myPopup, #btn-cerrar").toggle();
}
```

```css
/* Popup container - can be anything you want */

.popup {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  text-decoration: underline;
}


/* The actual popup */

.popup .popuptext {
  /*   background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95); */
  display: none;
  background-color: white;
  color: #3e3e3f;
  padding: 8px 10px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 10%;
  left: 30%;
  margin-left: -80px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 6px 8px -2px rgba(221, 221, 221, .5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 6px 8px -2px rgba(221, 221, 221, .5);
  box-shadow: 0px 6px 8px -2px rgba(221, 221, 221, .5);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .popup .popuptext {
    left: 35%;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.96);
  }
}

.popuptext {
  margin: 15px;
}


/* Popup arrow */

.popup .popuptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-color: white;
}


/* Toggle this class - hide and show the popup 
.popup .show {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
  animation: fadeIn 1s;
}
*/


/* Add animation (fade in the popup) 
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  from {opacity: 0;} 
  to {opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {opacity: 0;}
  to {opacity:1 ;}
 
}

*/

.lista-popup {
  width: 550px;
  margin: 10px;
  left: -5px;
}

.lista-info-plants {
  width: 550px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:767px) {
  .lista-info-plants {
    width: 340px;
    margin: 10px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:767px) {
  .lista-popup {
    width: 340px;
    margin: 10px;
  }
}


/*
.cerrar-popup{
  display:none;
  background-color: #ff6b6b;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 700;
  border-radius: 1000px;
  border: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  z-index: 1500;
}
*/


/* added CSS code by LaurentC */

#myPopup {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-left: 250px;
}

.lista-popup {
  position: relative;
}

#btn-cerrar {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
  background-color: #ff6b6b;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 700;
  border-radius: 1000px;
  border: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  z-index: 1500;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()">
  <h2><strong>¿Cómo funciona?</strong></h2>
  <div class="popuptext" id="myPopup">
    <div class="lista-popup">
      <button class="cerrar-popup" onclick="myFunction()" id="btn-cerrar"> X </button>
      <h3>Te explicamos como funciona :)</h3>
      <ol>
        <li class="lista-info-plants">Selecciona la plantita que quieres, tenemos 3 opciones.</li>
        <br>
        <li class="lista-info-plants">Para enviar las plantitas, utilizamos envío del día siguiente para que tu plantita no sufra.</li>
        <br>
        <li class="lista-info-plants">El envío del día siguiente cuenta a partir de que la maceta sale de nuestras instalaciones. En realidad necesitamos unos días para sembrar la pantita y empacarla bien.</li>
        <br>
        <li class="lista-info-plants">Por el momento solo enviamos cactus y suculentas, pues son los que mejor aguantan los traslados.</li>
        <br>
        <li class="lista-info-plants">Por último, te recordamos que tener una plantita es como una mascota, hay que cuidar de ella y darle lo que necesita para sobrevivir :) </li>
        <br>
      </ol>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Codepen to play with my new version: https://codepen.io/larrytherabbit/pen/YzqeOwe

Comment: Thanks Laurent, still not working, this snippet is already live, but not working!

Comment: did you also update the CSS code? I changed visibility:hidden to display:none for the 3 elements, so it wouldn't work if not changed too.

Comment: Yeah! I used the same styles you added in your answer!

Comment: OK, well on the top of my head I'm thinking maybe some unwanted interaction with code from the libraries you usee ... let me check again the new live version!

Comment: OK. Is it still the same URL for the live preivew? (https://zkuzrjax2mmihlq6-7442563129.shopifypreview.com/collections/macetas/products/copy-of-porta-macetas-de-aluminio-edicion-oro-especial)           // Because it works for me in 3 different browsers. **Did you clear your cache? Maybe you're loading an old style sheet or old scriptfile in cache.

Comment: Tried clearing cache, also tried the solution Angel posted with no luck.

Comment: Wow. OK. You're on Chrome > 84 I assume? Well, well. At this point, I would need to work directly on (a copy) of your current stage website version. But I totally understand if you are reluctant. The issue is that somewhere somehow between here and your site something gets lost or transformed, I don't know. Otherwise, you know what, I'll recode your popup box in a more simple way, entirely. With a very lean code, but I'll redo everything html css etc. It would take me maybe 10 minutes. Would you prefer that? We both spent a lot of time, it has to work! Lol. I also never give up.

Comment: It's a very simple thing to code, it shouldn't be so hard to accomplish like that.

Comment: Hey! You're very kind, thanks. The thing is it is a Shopify store that uses a templating language called liquid that compiles in the backend and renders an HTML, so maybe there's some conflict at some point in the process! If there's no problem with you, I'd love to try a new solution (cause I'm also learning web development and can benefit of that!) Otherwise, I might just add some underline text inside the popup simulating a close button (without the actual functionality), just for people to know they can actually close the popup!

Comment: That could explain the weird results! I didn't know that Shopify was like WP. I'm supposed to work with that framework very soon (Shopify) so it's good to know ahead what I'll be dealing with haha. Well basically all there is to know really is that you set the `display` to `none` for the element to show when we click on the other (trigger) element, and `.toggle()` (jQuery) the `display` between `block` and `none` using that trigger (button, link, text, whatever element you put the `onclick=function()` on. That's it!

Comment: For the sake of it, here is a very simplified codepen. Took exactly 2 minutes to code. https://codepen.io/larrytherabbit/pen/yLOvRYb Good luck and you can email me if you're stuck laurentchevrette (at) gmail (dot) com      // cheers

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll try it as soon as I get back!